# How do override a method through a class you're extending, while still running the code in the original class you're overriding?

Tags: java, oop

I have a game system with a base class called `GameRoom`.

In this class I have some boilerplate code for what every `GameRoom` instance needs.

In individual room classes I extend the `GameRoom` class, overriding the `update` and `render` methods of the base `GameRoom` class, but that makes my tilemaps etc. not render.

I want the boilerplate code to keep rendering whilst being able to run a custom one (with the exact same name) within the `GameRoom` subclasses.

How do I do that?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `super.overridedMethod()` ? In other words do you want to call the function you overrided from the new implementation of the function?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right! Since tilemap rendering happens in the original class it wont "transfer" to the new class, so it doesnt happen because the entire method is overridden in the new implementation.

Comment: I'm certain this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something like:

```java
abstract class Room{
    abstract void render(Canvas c){
        //impl goes here
    }
}
```

Then in your subclasses you can do:

```java
class SpecificRoom extends Room{
    void render(Canvas c){
        super.render(c);//calls the code in Room.render
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call an overridden method by using [`super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) instead of `this`.

```
class Example extends Parent {
  @Override
  void method() {
    super.method(); // calls the overridden method
  }
}
```

If you want to *force* every subclass to call a method from the parent class, Java doesn't provide a direct mechanism for that. But you can use a final function that calls abstract functions to allow a similar behavior (the [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)).

```
abstract class Parent {
  final void template() { // the template method
    System.out.println("My name is " + this.nameHook());
  }
  protected abstract String nameHook(); // the template "parameter"
}

class Child {
  @Override
  protected String nameHook() {
    return "Child"
  }
}
```

Then you can run the program by calling the template method, which is only defined by the parent class, and it will call the subclasses' hook methods, which they all must have implemented.